# effective importing of .csv to mysql to several related tables

Tags: mysql, csv

Could you please tell me how to effectively allow the user to import their data in mysql?
The problem is that data generally need to be inserted in several related tables.
Importing importing .csv of severl 10s or 100s thousand of line take much time and generate large load for database. Now I parse .csv, generate insets (maybe several inserts if we need to set attrributes in related table) and in loop insert data in tha database.
How do you do such things? 
Maybe to load file on server and on the server periodacally to insert data by little portions?
All ideas are appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need to insert all this data, I don't think you have much of a choice.

I would recommend using inserting multiple rows with one INSERT to reduce the number of round-trips between the application and the database:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (....)
VALUES (....),
       (....);
```

If you are inserting the data for the first time, you could create the indexes after all the data has been inserted, but of course if you're doing this online (i.e. your insertion process is executing concurrently with other operations) then you can't do that as the indexes are shared between all processes.

Comment: I have data like this: entrites table
entity_id attr1 attr2 attr3
1
...
n

string_attributes
entity_d field_id value
1

number_attributes
entity_id field_id value

date_attribtutes
entity_id field_id value

Comment: It's not quite clear how to insers multiple rows of entities, I think it's impossible, because we need to get id of the last inserted entity.

Comment: As for attributes of one type for the concrete entity, multiple rows insert is used.

Comment: Yes, it online, so we can't disable indexing before importing data.

Comment: Maybe it's worth to insert data in the database by small portions.

Comment: I see your problem with getting the last inserted ID, I can't think of a way to solve that. What would the benefit be of inserting the data in small portions?

Comment: Maybe it will not generate high load for the server (the problem could be even worse if many userS would import large amount of data at the same time).